# How get consistent names for Pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I want to run this docker image in kubernetes:
https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq

This is not a problem, and it is running. The problem is that I need to send through switches do the "docker run" command. For this image, when starting the container in docker you would run this:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

The yaml file will then look something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:  
  name: rb
  namespace: rabbittest
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: rb
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rb-container
        env:                    
          - name: HOSTNAME
            value: "rbnode001"
        image: rabbitmq:3-management        
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        volumeMounts:
          - name: azure
            mountPath: /mnt/azure
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5672
      volumes:
      - name: azure
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-secret
          shareName: rabbittest
          readOnly: false
```

My question is, how do I get kubernetes to apply the --name and --hostname when kubernetes executes the "docker run" commands?

Comment: what is your purpose? why do you need `--name` & `--hostname` when running in kuberneres?

Comment: Because that is a requirement for running that particular image in docker. From the documentation: One of the important things to note about RabbitMQ is that it stores data based on what it calls the "Node Name", which defaults to the hostname. What this means for usage in Docker is that we should specify -h/--hostname explicitly for each daemon so that we don't get a random hostname and can keep track of our data

Comment: so, you want to set nodename in env?

Comment: No, "hostname". It can be any value. Like "RabbitMQ0001" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to create `StatefulSets` to `RabbitMQ`.

In your StatefulSet, add this `ENV`.

```
env:
  - name: POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.name
  - name: POD_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  - name: K8S_SERVICE_NAME
    value: rabbitmq-headless
  - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
    value: $(POD_NAME).$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
```

Here, `K8S_SERVICE_NAME` is headless service required by statefulset.

Finally, `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` will hold the HOSTNAME.

Comment: EDIT : I am wrong, it looks like this overrides the actual names K8S assigns to pods to whatever I want. I will give this a shot.
----------------------

This will not result in what the question is asking for. The resulting command that Kubernetes generates when it creates the container in docker should be "docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3". The solution you provided here will not generate that, it will generate something like "docker run --env POD_NAME=xxxxx --env POD_NAMESPACE=yyyyy"

Comment: There is no direct solution to your question. You need work around

Comment: I have accepted this answer. Stateful sets create pods with predictable names, allowing me to reference them consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes's options are just different from Docker's options.  Many options have equivalents in the [pod spec object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#podspec-v1-core); some options don't have direct equivalents, or are split into multiple layers (volume mounts, published ports).

For the two options you mention:

- `docker run --name` sets the name of the container.  In Kubernetes you don't usually directly interact with containers, so you can't set their names.  The `metadata: {name: }` sets the name of the Deployment, and generated Pods have names derived from that; the containers within a Pod also have names but it's very rare to use these.
- `docker run --hostname` sets the name a container believes its hostname is.  You almost never need this option; RabbitMQ is the notable exception.  The pod spec has a `hostname:` option that can set this.

  ```yaml
  spec:
    template:
      spec:
        hostname: my-rabbit
        containers: [...]
  ```

As [@Shahriar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830162/10008173) suggests, a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) is a better match for deployments that need some backing persistent state.  In this case [the StatefulSet automatically sets the host name based on the pod identity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id), so you don't need to do anything.

(The important detail for RabbitMQ is that the hostname must be consistent across recreating the container, and if the hostname is always `rb-0` from a StatefulSet that satisfies this rule.  An autogenerated Docker container ID, or a variable Kubernetes Deployment pod name, will be different on every restart, and Rabbit will lose track of its state.)

Comment: The inconsistent hostname was exactly my problem with RabbitMQ. StatefulSet solves this problem for me.