# How to access specific endpoint of Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

In Kubernetes in order to access a pod or a replicated pod we use a service. So under a specific service there are a number of pods with the same label. What i am looking for is the following:

If i want to send a request into a specific pod of the service, is any way to do that?

Comment: Try a combination of giving the pod a consistent name (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829279/how-get-consistent-names-for-pods-in-kubernetes) by using stateful sets and then connect to it using that name. It's not a common pattern to communicate with a specific pod though because the pods are meant to be ephemeral but this will (probably) do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the purpose of the service to to be able to use either pod. If you want to connect to a specific pod, you should have a different service for each pod you want to connect to independently.